# How to Select all from two tables using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have two tables.

Table 1. named `student`

Table 2. named `parent`

student has `student_id` so as parent table

I want to write and sql for example to select ALL from student and ALL from parent where `student.student_id`=`parent.student_id` and where `student.student_id` = 14.

I have tried so many SQL i felt should work but none worked for example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM student AS s 
   JOIN parent AS p
  ON s.student_id = p.student_id
WHERE s.student_id = 14
```

will like to know what i am doing wrong

edit:

Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'p.student_id' in 'on clause'

Both students and parents tables just contain names, mobile, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this

SELECT * 
  FROM student AS s, parent AS p
WHERE s.student_id = p.student_id AND s.student_id = 14

if you are referred student_id as an Integer this is ok and if it is Varchar it should be 
s.student_id="14"

Comment: thanks, i was able to refraction your SQL a bit and it worked